# React Axios - C# WebAPI request token fails without a server error

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, fetch, axios

I have the following code:

```
var qs = require('qs');

const ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:56765/';
const data = qs.stringify({ username, password, grant_type: 'password' });
axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}token`, data)
.then(response => {
    debugger;
    dispatch(authUser());
    localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
})
.catch((error) => {
    debugger;
    dispatch(authError(error.response));
});
```

When I run this code, I hit the debugger and the error object has `Error: Network Error at createError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2188:15) at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1724:14)` in the catch block. However, in the network tab in Chrome, the Status code is 200, but when I click on the response/preview tabs of this request there is no data. If I click on continue, I actually get the token and other data in the response/preview tab as expected, but at this point it has already reached the catch block so will not hit the then block.

I have even debugged the back-end and it doesn't send back an error, so I assume this is a front end error. Does anyone know what is causing this?

Edit:

Just to add more details, if I change the request to work with fetch instead of axios, I am getting a different error `TypeError: Failed to fetch`. The code used for the call is:

```
fetch(`${ROOT_URL}token`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
})
```

Also, this is an example of the postman request working correctly:
[image]

Comment: Do you use `static` server? The error url `'http://localhost:3000/static/js'` is a different to your action url `'http://localhost:56765/token'`. This is just assumption, so i might be wrong

Comment: What is a static server? My server is a default C# WebAPI

Comment: I think this is related to this [github issue about an axios bug](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/362), maybe you can try some workaround posted in.

Comment: @Dyo Just spent a few hours trying all the things in the above thread. None of them worked; I still got the same errors. Thanks for trying though

Comment: Since this appears to be web api token request, you should probably enable https. When https is disabled, you get a silent failure with no response from postman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found my answer. It turns out I had not enabled CORS in my WebAPI back-end for the `/token` endpoint. The way I was able to resolve this was by enabling CORS in the `MyProject\Providers\ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs` by adding the line `context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });` to the top of the method named `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials`. I do think there are better ways to enable CORS for the entire project which I will look into next!

Got some help from here about how to enable the CORS: [Enable CORS for Web Api 2 and OWIN token authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285253/enable-cors-for-web-api-2-and-owin-token-authentication)

Comment: I add this to WebApiConfig.cs: // Use NuGet to add this: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
            config.EnableCors();

Comment: Yes, just to clarify, I found you can enable CORS globally in the `WebApiConfig.cs` by doing `var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(
            origins: "*", 
            headers: "*", 
            methods: "*");
         config.EnableCors(cors);` but you still need to enable CORS in `ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs` for the token request

Answer (score 1):

It should work with fetch by adding content-type :

```
fetch(`${ROOT_URL}token`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'},
    body: data
})
```

You can try this in axios too but it seems related to an [axios bug](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/362), you can give a try by adding the `params` property :

```
axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}token`, data, params: data)
```

Comment: The fetch had the same issue and the axios post has an error of `expected 1-3 arguments, but got 4` which is weird because there are only 3. But when I did it as `axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}token`, data, data)` I got the usual error. Thanks for the try tho

Comment: What about this : ``axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}token`, data: {}, params: data)`` ?

Comment: It thinks there are 5 parameters when I do that... I think you cant define the name when you are calling a method, and it looks for the parameters in the order they are being defined so the colon is useless there.